# PySide Child Window

Tags: python, qt5, pyside

I want to open a child window in the `MainWindow` of my app. I want to disallow the user to interact with the parent window, and only allow him to open that child window once. For example, the 'About' window in many applications.

```
class Ui_AboutDialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(500, 300)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 300))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 300))
        MainWindow.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.English, QtCore.QLocale.UnitedStates))
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 481, 181))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        #MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
```

Here is how I call it in the `MainWindow`:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        ...
        ...
        self.actionAbout.triggered.connect(lambda: self.openAbout(MainWindow))

    def openAbout(self, MainWindow):
        aboutDialog = QtGui.QDialog(MainWindow)
        aboutUi = Ui_AboutDialog()
        aboutUi.setupUi(aboutDialog)
        aboutDialog.show()

       ...
       ...
```

---

### Solution

```
def openAbout(self, MainWindow):
    if self.AboutDialog is None:
        self.AboutDialog = QtGui.QDialog(MainWindow)
        aboutUi = Ui_AboutDialog()
        aboutUi.setupUi(self.AboutDialog)
    self.AboutDialog.setModal(True)
    self.AboutDialog.show()
```

`self.AboutDialog` is set to `None` in `setupUi` of `class Ui_MainWindow`.

I think while using `self.AboutDialog.setModal(True)` we may go without `self.AboutDialog` as follows:

```
def openAbout(self, MainWindow):
    AboutDialog = QtGui.QDialog(MainWindow)
    aboutUi = Ui_AboutDialog()
    aboutUi.setupUi(AboutDialog)
    AboutDialog.setModal(True)
    AboutDialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not explicitly stated, I assume you are asking how to make the `QDialog` only appear once? If so, how about implementing a variable in your `Ui_MainWindow` class which tracks whether the child window has already been opened once before. You could easily modify your `openAbout` function to check this variable and only open the child window if it hasn't been opened before.

Comment: how can disallow the user from interacting with parent window while the child dialog is still opened ?

Comment: As mentioned [here](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QDialog.html#modal-dialogs), you need to set the `QDialog` as a modal. Use `setModal(true)` and check out the first paragraph of the link I included for a thorough explanation. Hope this helps.